# uppercase and lowercase in c

Tags: uppercase, lowercase

I have tried to figure out why the program doesn't work. It turns lowercase to uppercase, let's say I type "k", it returns K. Then I continue typint "A", it doesn't return "a", but exits. But why? Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){


char UPPER,LOWER;

printf("Enter UPPERCASE\n");
UPPER = getchar();
if (UPPER >= 65 && UPPER <= 90) 

{ 
    UPPER = UPPER + 32;
    printf("The UPPERCASE now is %c\n", UPPER);

}

printf("Enter lowercase\n");
LOWER = getchar();
if (LOWER >= 97 && LOWER <= 122)

{

    LOWER = LOWER - 32;
    printf("The lowercase now is %c\n", LOWER);

}


getchar();
getchar();

}
```

Comment: When you run it in the debugger or print `UPPER` and `LOWER` (bad variable names BTW, try `upper` and `lower` instead) what are their values?

Answer (score 0):

If you compile and run this code:

```
    void main(void)
    {
        char c = getchar();
        printf("c = %d %c\n", c, c);
        c = getchar();
        printf("c = %d %c\n", c, c);
    }
```

You will see this output:

```
    user@host ~/work/tmp $ ./test
    a
    c = 97 a
    c = 10 
    /* new line there*/
```

This code is not the same, but works:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    #define BUFSIZE 4
    int main(void)
    {
        char UPPER[BUFSIZE] = {0}, LOWER[BUFSIZE] = {0};
        int i;

        printf("Enter UPPERCASE\n");
        fgets(UPPER, BUFSIZE, stdin);
        for(i = 0; i < BUFSIZE; i++)
        {
            if (UPPER[i] >= 65 && UPPER[i] <= 90) 

            { 
                UPPER[i] = UPPER[i] + 32;
            }
        }
        printf("The UPPERCASE now is %s", UPPER);

        printf("Enter LOWERCASE\n");
        fgets(LOWER, BUFSIZE, stdin);

        for(i = 0; i < BUFSIZE; i++)
        {
            if (LOWER[i] >= 97 && LOWER[i] <= 122) 

            { 
                LOWER[i] = LOWER[i] - 32;
            }
        }
        printf("The LOWERCASE now is %s", LOWER);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should separately add `getchar();`, after `printf("The UPPERCASE now is %c\n", UPPER);`
and again after `printf("The lowercase now is %c\n", LOWER);`.
Most of the program is ending with getch(),and so we think that getch() is used to display the output...but it is wrong.It is used to get a single character from the console.
your correct code should be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
char UPPER, LOWER;
printf("Enter UPPERCASE\n");
UPPER = getchar();
if (UPPER >= 65 && UPPER <= 90)

{
UPPER = UPPER + 32;
printf("The UPPERCASE now is %c\n", UPPER);

}
getchar();
printf("Enter lowercase\n");
LOWER = getchar();
if (LOWER >= 97 && LOWER <= 122)

{

LOWER = LOWER - 32;
printf("The lowercase now is %c\n", LOWER);

}
getchar();
}
```

Comment: Now I only have to put all the code into a while loop, until I enter EOF. Any suggestions?

Comment: No problems, but I am stuck with EOF, don't know how to use it properly in the while loop

Comment: i don't understand your query,do you want to print both values at end?

Comment: What I meant was this: I need to use EOF in the while loop, but the EOF doesn't work.